# AutoOpen taskpanes only open on computer where the document is created

Tags: openxml, office-js, word-addins

**Context**

Currently I am developing a Word add-in that uses the new Javascript API's for Office. The add-in consists of some basic functionalities and a number templates. The templates (plain documents) automatically opens a taskpane when the document is opened. I have followed the [following guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document) to achieve this. Manually adjusting the OOXML (webextensions) did not result in the desired effect. Fortunately, I was successful with implementing the automatically opening taskpanes via the [API functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document#tag-the-document-on-the-client-side) offered in Office.js

**The Problem**

The add-in manifests are hosted on the local filesystem (C:\AddInManifests). When a document is created and is adjusted to automatically open a taskpane on opening, it works only on the computer where it is created. More specifically it only works on the computer where the client side API methods are called to specify that the document has an automatically opening taskpane.

My suspicion is that it sees the add-ins of the two different computers as two different add-ins entirely. I am looking for way to overcome this, if it is possible to overcome.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<we:webextension xmlns:we="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/webextension/2010/11" id="{C3B1DD62-B056-4FA5-BF7F-5F3800D7C339}">
    <we:reference id="4a53b5db-f60a-4c32-82ee-2cf3f4954538" version="1.0.0.1" store="\\.\C:\AddInManifests\" storeType="Filesystem"/>
    <we:alternateReferences/>
    <we:properties>
        <we:property name="Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument" value="true"/>
    </we:properties>
    <we:bindings/>
    <we:snapshot xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"/>
 </we:webextension>
```

**EDIT**

My suspicions seems validated. These problems do not arise when centralized deployment is used. So my presumption is that the manifests on a local harddisk will be seen as a different add-in on a different computer even though the manifest is located on the same location.

Answer (score 1):

Settings like AutoOpen are specific to the manifest ID. For example, settings applied to a document via side-loaded add-in will not be seen when that add-in is published via Office Store (different manifest ID).